# PEP8 in Eclipse has issues with Umlaut

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pep8

I found a strange behaviour of the pep8 checker in Eclipse (used to happen in Luna, still there after I updated to Mars):

```
myDict = {'a':      # This is fine
          'b'}      # fine

myDict = {'ä':      # fine
          'b'}      # fine

myTuple = ('a',     # fine
           'b')     # fine

myTuple = ('ä',     # fine
           'b')     # fine

myC = ('a', {'b': 'c',   # fine
             'd': 'e'})  # fine

myC = ('ä', {'b': 'c',   # fine
             'd': 'e'})  # E128: continuation line under-indented[...]
```

This happens only when I check "Use system interpreter" in
Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis -> pep8.py
(which I need because I want to specify additional arguments).

The source file is encoded as UTF-8. There is no problem when I run pep8.exe or pep8.py on that file manually.

I don't get it - anyone an idea how to fix that or where it comes from?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that behaviour. I copied your code and pep8 was ok. I tried removing one space and the E128 message appeared, so it is working. If that's something that bother you, you can ignore E128: PyDev > Editor > Code Analysis > pep8.py > Arguments > `--ignore=E128`. I am running Kepler with PyDev 3.7  (yeah I know, too lazy to update) on OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: Strange. But thanks for your effort! Simply ignoring the error doesn't satisfy me though ;)

Comment: If possible, try to reproduce that behaviour in a different machine, specifically, different OS and/or different Eclipse/PyDev versions.

Comment: Are you using python 2? Is the file utf-8 encoded at the top-line?

Comment: I tried in another machine and got the same behaviour as before. Running Eclipse Luna (4.4.0) with PyDev 4.1 on Linux 3.16. Python 2 on both machines. Tried with and without the encoding at the top line.

Comment: I have Python 3 installed, so there should be no need to specify the encoding. I will try it anyway...

Comment: There is an open issue for this exact bug in the pep8 GitHub repo, by the way: https://github.com/PyCQA/pep8/issues/391

Comment: @MartinValgur thanks for the link. Running pep8 from the console reproduces the same error for me. Weirdly, it does not happen within Eclipse. I also tried with the example given in that issue. Probably something related with my setup. Note: I didn't have pep8 installed as a standalone (i.e, installed with pip and executable with pep8 src.py) -- which I did install in order to run the example of the gh issue --, so I guess the version that Eclipse is running is somehow different.